# problems with cURL and probably Apache

Tags: php, apache, curl

I'm importing some data from external domains successful with cURL, until I tried with this URI: http://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/760186.ics?s=29623a93eb0e693c77591a711f082f06, which is a ics calendar.
I can successfully run it on a command line (try for your selves):
shell>> curl https://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/760660.ics?s=593cc556438a8f0919beb6107b6f508d, so it's not a network issue.

but my php script (that do return other URI) DO NOT return this. or better it return false.

here is the small php

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$ical1= "http://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/760186.ics?s=29623a93eb0e693c77591a711f082f06";
echo file_get_contents_curl($ical1);
```

I do think this has something to do with my apache or php configuration, because it runs on appfog and it run with my old xampp instalation.
To resume: all URI worked with old xampp instalation and now just the one from the example fails.

on my phpinfo() i can read:

```
cURL support enabled
cURL Information 7.24.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS Yes
Debug No
GSS-Negotiate Yes
IDN No
IPv6 Yes
Largefile Yes
NTLM Yes
SPNEGO No
SSL Yes
SSPI Yes
krb4 No
libz Yes
CharConv No
Protocols dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host i386-pc-win32
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1c
ZLib Version 1.2.5
libSSH Version libssh2/1.3.0
```

Comment: just tried on my mamp setup and your script worked fine (first url redirects to second one that outputs the calendar data). try reading curl_error() as you get $data==null

Comment: curl_error gives an empty string, by the manual says that no error occurred. thanks i hadn't tried yet.
(the return submits the message is a pain...)
This problem happens on a windows server, I'm giving up and moving to a linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function get_remoteDATA($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //If POST METHOD IS NEEDED
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=1&var2=2&var3=3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 9);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$cntn= get_remoteDATA('http://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/760186.ics?s=29623a93eb0e693c77591a711f082f06');
print_r($cntn);
```